# ASP.NET MVC Creating duplicate records on creating object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET, and I'm running into a very odd issue with duplicate records. I'll dive into code here:

I have a Company model defined as:

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual SubscriptionType SubscriptionType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

And a SubscriptionType model defined as:

```
public class SubscriptionType
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SubscriptionTypeDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SubscriptionType> SubscriptionTypes { get; set; }
}
```

The SubscriptionType data is set in the Seed function with the following:

```
var subscriptionTypes = new List<SubscriptionType>
        {
            new SubscriptionType { Name= "Free" },
            new SubscriptionType { Name= "Business" },
            new SubscriptionType { Name= "Enterprise" },
        };
        subscriptionTypes.ForEach(s => context.SubscriptionTypes.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

And when I try to create a user in the public async Task Register function (I'm using the default ApplicationUser) I use the following code to create a Company when a user is registering:

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var subscription = db.SubscriptionTypes.Find(1);
            var company = new Company { Name = model.CompanyName, DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow, SubscriptionType = subscription };
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Company = company };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Now - the Company should have 1 set as the SubscriptionType_ID, but instead, it creates a duplicate record in the SubscriptionType table and sets the SubscriptionType_ID to 4.

```
ID | Name
-----------
1  | Free
2  | Business
3  | Enterprise
4  | Free
```

This is my ApplicationDBContext:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<SubscriptionType> SubscriptionTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Collection> Collections { get; set; }
```

Why would it be creating a duplicate record in this case?

Comment: try adding entity framework to your list of tags

Comment: You company class needs a navigation property for the foreign key - [Relationships and Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj713564.aspx)

Comment: I tried adding SubscriptionTypeID - unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: The problem will not persist if you have correctly defined you navigation properties (and you set the value of `SubscriptionTypeID` when saving (not `SubscriptionType`)

Comment: But it should really work, when `SubscriptionType` is assigned like in asked question, should't it? I mean you don't have to explicitly assign foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating new instance of your `Company` class - from Entity Framework's point of view - it's brand new `Company`, which happens to have the same `Name` value (you could read more here: [Entity Framework Change Tracking](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/change-tracking-in-entity-framework.aspx)).

You should propably check, if company provided by user already exists in your database and if it does, you should retrievie this company and assign it, to `Company` property in `ApplicationUser` class.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but the record that is getting duplicated is SubscriptionType. There should only be 3, which are created in the Seed function, but for some reason, it is creating a duplicate record when I create a new company.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry - I missed that part, that we are talking about `SubscriptionType`. Did you tried using `var subscription = db.SubscriptionTypes.FirstOrDefault(type => type.ID == 1);`? Find performs search by primary key - if `FirstOrDefault` will not result with duplicate `SubscriptionType`, then I guess there is something wrong with ID being primary key.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion now - but it appears to still be creating a new record in the SubscriptionType table.

Comment: I just realized one suspicious thing - change tracking in Entity Framework is being internally done by DbContext, but SubscriptionType and Company are in two different DbContexts. Are those two in two different databases? You are saving changes to yet another third ApplicationDbContext, so this context has no clue about this retrieved SubscriptionType being "old" entity and maybe treats it like new one. Did you try to put Companies and SubscriptionTypes in one DbContext and use this DbContext to save your data?

Comment: Another idea, if `SubscriptionType` is indeed in `ApplicationDbContext`, would be [attaching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx) this entity to context. If they are in the same context, then your code should work (as far I can tell), but maybe there is something more going on, that is not included in snippets in your question.

Comment: There should only be 1 context. I added my ApplicationDBContext to the original post. I tried removing the DbSet from all individual models, but the problem persists. I also tried using SubcriptionTypeID = 1 in the Company constructor, which actually does prevent the problem from happening. But the question remains - why does setting the SubscriptionType = subscription create a new record in the SubscriptionType table?

Comment: This behaviour is indeed weird. Try adding after `var subscription = db.SubscriptionTypes.Find(1);` line `db.SubscriptionTypes.Attach(subscription);` and see what the result is.

Comment: It is very odd, yes. I just tried your suggestion - no luck unfortunately.